# after reset .bashrc nvm not working

Tags: bash, nvm

I was installing android SDK and messed up my bashrc file. after reseting bashrc nvm no longer works.
What lines should I add to .bashrc so it works again?

Comment: How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Well, may be share your own bashrc here and highlight lines which are relevant to nvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm maintainer here. If you simply rerun the install script, it will put the correct lines back in.